# How to access a Tensorflow docker instance from the "outside" without Jupyter - for distributed Tensorflow

Tags: docker, tensorflow

I have nvidia-docker and the tensorflow-gpu image functioning fine on Ubuntu 14.04, Python 2.7.

At this point, I can only figure out how to access Tensorflow in two ways - by running the following command, I'm able to access Tensorflow from the host machine in Jupyter notebook with the port 8888.

```
nvidia-docker run -it -p 8888:8888 gcr.io/tensorflow/tensorflow:latest-gpu
```

By running the following command I'm able to run an interactive shell in which I can run Python scripts or the REPL.

```
nvidia-docker run -it gcr.io/tensorflow/tensorflow:latest-gpu /bin/bash
```

My problem is that I wish to run Tensorflow distributed across a few computers, and as far as I'm aware Jupyter won't work well for this because code needs to be run in the notebook itself.
The interactive shell won't really work either because it doesn't map to any port or allow external connections.

Has anyone had luck with running distributed Tensorflow from the docker image? How did you do it?